# How to escape "," for writing CSV files

Tags: c#, csv

I have variables like these :

```
string text1 = "its my text";
string text2 = "really";
string text3 = "it's mine";
```

And i have string builder:

```
StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();
```

I'm concatenate all strings to one:

```
string forAppend = text1+ "," + text2 + "," + text3 + ",";
csvcontent.AppendLine(forAppend);
```

I'm separating them with "," because i want them to separated cells in excel. Last step i'm writing this data to excel :

```
File.AppendAllText(path, csvcontent.ToString());
```

It's working good. But if i have "," in a string it's separating cell. I just want to have 3 cells how can i escape "," in string variable?

Comment: That's not an excel file, that's a CSV file...

Comment: Enclose fields in double quotes

Comment: Save yourself a headache and use a CSV parser library.